# Youtube api search query exclude multiple words

Tags: java, android, youtube-api

I'm trying to set the q param for youtube 'search' api request to **exclude** a phrase with multiple words.

E.g I want to exclude the phrases "Cardi B" and "Ed Sheeran" from my results. 
I tried some variations based on the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
but could not depict the right way.

This will exclude all four words (anything that has 'cardi or 'b' or 'ed' or 'sheeran' inside it):

q = "-cardi -b -ed -sheeran"

This will try to match those that don't have Cardi but do have B, don't have ed but do have sheeran, (plus is replaced by space):

q = "-cardi+b -ed+sheeran"

how do I exclude all videos that contain "Ed Sheeran" or "Cardi B"?

I'm using the JAVA api but this syntax applies to all sdks

Thank's alot

Amir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use negative quotes around each phrase, but you'll probably need a positive match phrase too.

```
q='music -"cardi b" -"ed sheeran"'
```

Comment: Tnx, working! Tried that but using the escape code of the double quotes rather than actual quotes.